# Why does this code run slower on spoj, triggering the timeout?

Tags: haskell

I was trying to solve this problem on spoj: http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/

My code works fine and fast on my laptop (even slower cpu than the one that spoj provides) but spoj keeps giving me time exceeded:

```
import Control.Monad

main = do
        num <- getLine
        inputs <- replicateM (read num) getLine
        test inputs

test [] = return ()
test (l:ls) = do
    putStrLn (send l)
    test ls

send :: String -> String
send str
    | odd (length str) = makePalindrome str (take (length str `div` 2 + 1) str ++ ( reverse $ take (length str `div` 2) str))
    | otherwise        = makePalindrome str (take (length str `div` 2) str ++ (reverse $ take (length str `div` 2) str))
makePalindrome :: String -> String  -> String
makePalindrome str pal 
        | (read str :: Integer) < (read pal :: Integer) = pal
        | otherwise = makePalindrome str (nextPalindrome pal)


nextPalindrome :: String -> String
nextPalindrome (x:xs) = succ' ++ (reverse $ take rightlen succ')
        where
            strlen = length (x:xs)
            allNine = all ( (==) '9') 
            odd' = odd strlen
            left = if odd' then take (strlen `div` 2 + 1) (x:xs)  else take (strlen `div` 2) (x:xs)
            rightlen = strlen - (length left)
            succ' = show (read left + 1)


checkPalindrome :: String -> Bool
checkPalindrome str = str == (reverse str)
```

Comment: have you read  https://wiki.haskell.org/SPOJ ?

Comment: also my personal diary in two years ago says that using `Data.ByteString` instead of `String` made it pass the SPOJ's PALIN problem.

Comment: Did you profile the code on your machine? I mean did you verify that on your laptop the code runs in less than the time required by spoj?

Comment: @ymonad , Bakuriu Thanks a lot, my code works in lesser than 0.5 s under 50000 digit but it freezes over that. Maybe I should try Data.ByteString

Comment: @SeoHaKim note that actually i used `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` for solving it because it was more convenient than `Data.ByteString` (at least two years ago) . https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html

Comment: As haskellers, maybe we should add a prominent banner in www.haskell.org: "Looking for speed? You will need Data.ByteString. Check it out! It is free!". And of course, respect and love to the package maintainers ;-)

Comment: @Bakuriu wow I was wondering why my question looks better! Thanks

Comment: @ymonad Thanks. haskell is most interesting language I've ever learned!